# sp_blitz reporting both msdb backup history not purged and purged too frequently

Tags: sp-blitz

Just downloaded the last version of *sp_blitz* from github, and have run it on two different database servers.

On both of them it reports both of the following findings:

1. MSDB Backup History Not Purged
2. MSDB Backup History Purged Too Frequently

On one of the servers there were 2 years of backup history, but on the other there were only one month of backup history.

Anyone know why both of these are reported? Seems to contradict each other.

Could it be a *bug* in *sp_blitz*?

Comment: Yes, I noticed that yesterday too. I'd open up a new [issue on Github](https://github.com/BrentOzarULTD/SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue%20is%3Aopen%20msdb%20backup%20history) seeing as there are no open issues regarding this problem and explain what you found.

Comment: Look for closed issues, https://github.com/BrentOzarULTD/SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit/issues/1053. This has been logged and handled.

Comment: Thx to both. I just downloaded it again, and it seems that it has been fixed in the version uploaded some hours ago. Do they publish fixes only once a month, is that why I had the problem on the version downloaded 2 days ago, even though the issue was fixed and closed?